# importing csv into QGIS

Tags: csv, openstreetmap, qgis

So I am trying to transfer OSM data contained in a CSV document with OSM_way_id, OSM_start_node, OSM_end_node as columns, to QGIS. I want to represent this open street map data contained in the CSV as a map in QGIS. How do I do this? Please I need help.

Below is an example of the CSV when opened with Microsoft Excel. The CSV contains numerous rows and these columns:

| Year | Month | Day | Hour | osm_way_id | osm_start_node | osm_end_node | speed_mph_mean | speed_mph_stddev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 03 | 08 | 18 | 8179128 | 1343922650 | 108500 | 9.599 | 2.439 |

Comment: please, add an example of your csv-data

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/273169

Comment: @smvenk An example of the csv has been added

Comment: @pathmapper my data is different in the sense that, I have no longitude and latitude. Rather I have osm_way_id, osm_start_node, osm_end_node

Comment: without latitude, longitude you will not be able to display data on map.

To display your data in QGIS, you will need paths and nodes data from OSM.

In theory, the missing data can be obtained from the OSM server (if you have the skill of parsing xml files).  See - https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Downloading_data